# List of timezone abbreviations using xcode

Tags: ios, timezone, xcode5

I have retrieved a list of all the time zones using this function and storing them in an array :

```
    timeZoneElements = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] ;
```

I want to get the list of abbreviations , for example : GMT+1 … is there any easy and quick way to do that ?
 Many thanks

Edit 1 : This solution shows the timezones like follows : Asia/Beirut … therefore i need to show instead the GMT+2 label ..

Comment: Can you try sorting the array.

Comment: @user2071152 it's not about sorting , it's about displaying…please check my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This,

```
NSMutableArray *timeZoneArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]];
NSMutableArray *abbreviationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int count=0; count < [timeZoneArray count]-1; count=count+1)
{
    [abbreviationArray addObject:[[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[timeZoneArray objectAtIndex:count]] abbreviation]];
}

NSLog(@"Abbreviation : %@",abbreviationArray);
```

Comment: great i'm practically there!! but i only need the GMT+ factors to stored alone in an array…starting from your method how can i do it ? ( i +1 your answer to thank you ! )

Comment: it's not me i dunno ! i up voted it before but it has been removed and down voted…so i up voted it once again..something is not right maybe with my bad internet connection

Comment: You mean you want it to be only in the format of GMT+1 , GMT +2 ?

Comment: yes please…i would like to only store in the array the " GMT+1 " format without anything else

Comment: You should use the `description` method only for debugging purposes, because its exact output is not documented and may change at any time. (And just for the record: I did not downvote :-)

Comment: Why not use the `abbreviation` method instead?

Comment: @MartinR can you please show me how ? i would really appreciate it

Comment: *Abbreviation* is a good option, rather the right option for this scenario.